# Creating a formula, Same cell, Dynamic number of sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have created a workbook that has 2 sheets that will always be there: "Master" and "Score". On the Master sheet I have a named dynamic range where I will be inputting names, for instance(Mike, Sheila, Tom, and Matt) I have a macro that will take that list of names and create separate sheets. This list can vary from 3 to 20.

```
Sub create_ws()

    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim NewName As String

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("Master")


    'This Macro will create separate tabs based on a list in Master Tab K2 down

    Set MyRange = ws2.Range("K2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    screen 0, 1

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        If SheetExists(MyCell) Then
            NewName = InputBox("Sheet already exists, Please specify a unique name!", "New Copy")
                If NewName = vbNullString Or NewName = "" Then
                    screen 1
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = (NewName)
        Else
            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
            format_tabs (MyCell) 'calls next process to add named tabs
        End If
    Next MyCell

    screen 1

    ws2.Select
End Sub
```

On each sheet the format will be the same: column A and B are pre-filled with data and then columns C, D,and E are where the person will fill in their scoring information. The sheets and rows will vary, but the columns needed to average will always be the same.

What I am looking to do is on the "Score" sheet develop a macro that will build a formula that will average the responses in each sheet not with the static names and put them into the correct cell on the Scoring sheet. For instance if there are 11 issues the formula will be placed in `C2, D2, E2, C3, D3, E3`...all the way to `C12, D12, E12`. In `cell C2` on the score sheet the formula should read `=AVERAGE(Mike!C2,Sheila!C2,Tom!C2,Matt!C2)` and in `cell D2` the formula would read `=AVERAGE(Mike!D2,Sheila!D2,Tom!D2,Matt!D2)`

My named range is `GReviewers` and starts on `Master!K2`. I currently have helper cells but am looking to fully automate the workbook as well as expand my knowledge with VBA.

Here is some code I originally found. It sums all the sheets I need it to and puts it in the cell I need it to go in, but I need it to average it and if I could get the formula to display in the cell I would be able to use `.FillDown`.

```
Sub Totals()

Dim c As Range, mytotal As Double

mytotal = 0

    For Each c In Range("GReview")
        mytotal = mytotal + Sheets(c.Value).Range("C2")
    Next c
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Score").Range("C2") = mytotal

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried thusfar.  We are on SO to collaborate and help with coding, not a code-for-you service.

Comment: Can you edit your post and put that in there?  It's a bit difficult to read in the comment.  Just say once you've updated.  If you're copying in from VBA, make sure to put a tab (essentially 4 spaces) after highlighting the code, which should allow you to paste in more easily.  Otherwise you need to put 4 spaces before each line in your post so that the code-tool picks it up.

Comment: Updated to include Current code.

Comment: to average in VBA you can use Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("GReview").Value). The formula with a named range would be  =AVERAGE(GReview)

Comment: I have edited my original post to hopefully make it a little more clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing and researching I was able to solve my own question. If anyone have any neater way to code please feel free to add it on.

```
Sub b_form()
Dim c As Range
Dim myform As String
Dim r As Long
Dim x As Long

mytotal = 0
x = 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Score").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select

' count rows in a named range
Dim oRng As Range, lRows As Long
lRows = 0
For Each oRng In Range("GReview").Areas
lRows = lRows + oRng.Rows.Count
Next oRng

'Gets sheetnames and cells to build dynamic formula
 For r = 3 To 5
    For Each c In Range("GReview")
        If x <> lRows Then
            myform = myform + c & "!" & Cells(2, r).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=True) & ","
        Else
            myform = myform + c & "!" & Cells(2, r).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=True)
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Next c
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Score").Cells(2, r) = "=Average(" & myform & ")"
        myform = ""
        x = 1
Next r
' this calculation is no longer needed at this time
'Sheets("Score").Range("F2") = "=($C2*$D2)-(($C2*$D2)*($E2/5))"
 lr = get_lr(2)

With Sheets("Score").Range("C2:E" & lr)
    .FillDown
End With


End Sub
```